# Disputing a currency conversion that happened in a SWIFT transfer between accounts of the same currency

Tags: currency, international-transfer, eur-euro, swift, dispute

I made a SWIFT transfer from my EUR account in one bank (in Russia) to my EUR account in another bank (in the UK). However, the beneficiary bank received the transfer in GBP and converted it to EUR in order to match the currency of my account. But before that, it looks like my transfer experienced a EUR-to-GBP conversion first. That might have been done by middlemen involved (an Austrian, a French, or a UK bank). (I have the names of all intermediate banks participated.)

1. Does SWIFT protocol define any obligations of the involved parties in not performing unauthorised currency conversion?
2. If I ask the sender to initiate an investigation and it would reveal the specific intermediate bank that performed the EUR-to-GBP conversion, would I be able to dispute that conversion based on the SWIFT protocol or some other regulations?
3. Which body has the power to enforce the bank who made an error to correct that and compensate me the losses incurred by the conversion rate?